# Как перевести из String в String ^?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Как перевести из `String` в `String ^`?

Comment: А что есть String^? Что-то я такого не припоминаю в плюсах. Или это что-то из дельфи?

Comment: За что минусуете? Хороший же вопрос. Сам когда-то такую фигню городил, чтобы привести...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вот https://yadi.sk/d/OJztiinckNMZg

Comment: @Qwertiy А как вы решили проблему? И почему фигня?

Comment: Вроде ответил, cейчас студии под рукой нет проверить. Не, не фигня. Это я фигню городил, чтобы привести. А если конкретнее, то вставку пустой строки в нулевую позицию (wall)

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот полный код https://yadi.sk/d/znw8tiZrkNNBf

Comment: Я же ответил на твой вопрос. И вообще, код надо писать в вопросе текстом, а не в комментариях скриншотами, да ещё и на яндекс-диске.

Comment: @Qwertiy Сори, буду знать. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @АнтонВидович В идеале дополнить свой вопрос примерами кода, которые вы постили в виде изображений в комментариях и привести текст ошибок, чтобы вопрос был более полезен.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, вопрос и так полезен. Если кому достанется вдруг C++.NET, он поймёт. А от кода как раз пользы мало.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Скорее всего, следует просто создавать не `String`, а `String ^` за счёт использования `gcnew`:

```
String ^s1 = "qwe";
String ^s2 = gcnew String(L"Some text");
```

Если всё же по какой-то причине имеется именно `String`, то можно вызвать метод `ToString`:

```
String s;
...
String ^s3 = s.ToString();
```

---

В твоём случае

```
str2 += gcnew String(mas[i[j]], 1);
```

Но это жутко неэффективно. Для конкатенации строк следует использовать `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @АнтонВидович, ответ дополнен.